# Connecting Ektron with third party enterprise systems

Tags: ektron

I am working in ektron 8.6.

I am trying to connect a third party enterprise systems to ektron.

DxH has got a pre-built marketing automation connector,which is Marketo.

My third party enterprise connector is also a marketing automation system.

I am following the developer webinar to get this done.

Now,my question is eventhough i made establishing connection to the third party system by means of ConextBus API,i need to make some changes in the workarea files for implementing certain functionalities.

So is it necessary to have the connection established via DxH? 
What is the significance of this compared to handling all these functionalities from the ektron site?

Can anyone provide me some insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking "why use DxH?" the main answer is its tight integration with Ektron.  You can continue using your marketing automation system and it will share relevant data with Ektron.  If you are instead looking to perform a wholesale migration away from a particular system, you can certainly do a one-time import of data into Ektron using the APIs.  The difference there is that you would be moving away from the 3rd party system, whereas the DxH and its ContextBus allows both systems to work together.

You mentioned a webinar that you are following, so you may have already seen this, but there's a good webinar on the DxH here: http://www.ektron.com/Webinars/Details/Digital-Experience-Hub---Developer-Webinar/